# Listas con Linq asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

He estado leyendo sobre las listas en asp.net y su funcionamiento, actualmente tengo una aplicacion web donde hago bastantes consultas a la base de dato y por ello el rendimiento no es el deseado.

he hecho varios ejercicios introduciendo los datos a la lsita de forma manual

ejemplo:

```
ClaimedVehicles MyVehicles = new ClaimedVehicles(1, "hola", DateTime.Today, "MyModel", 1, "asas", "asas");
    ClaimedVehicles MyVehicles1 = new ClaimedVehicles(1, "hola", DateTime.Today, "P3", 1, "asas", "asas");
    ClaimedVehicles MyVehicles2 = new ClaimedVehicles(2, "hola", DateTime.Today, "P3", 1, "asas", "asas");

    List<ClaimedVehicles> MyListOFVehicles = new List<ClaimedVehicles>();
    MyListOFVehicles.Add(MyVehicles);
    MyListOFVehicles.Add(MyVehicles1);
    MyListOFVehicles.Add(MyVehicles2);

    MyListOFVehicles.Add(new ClaimedVehicles(1, "hola", DateTime.Today, "hi", 1, "asas", "asas"));
```

pero no logro comprender como lo tengo que hacer con una consulta a base de datos.

actualmente tengo una base de datos en access , he estado tratando de obtener los datos de la table usuarios

```
public class Users
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String NAME { get; set; }
        public int TEAM { get; set; }
        public int ROL_ID { get; set; }

        public Users(
            int id,
            String name,
            int team,
            int rol_id
            )
        {
            this.ID = id;
            this.NAME = name;
            this.TEAM = team;
            this.ROL_ID = rol_id;
        }
        private Users() { }
    }
```

y en mi lista algo asi:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ToolTrackSystem.List
{
    public class ListUsers
    {
        String myConnectionString = @"C:\Users\gutiece\Desktop" + "tool_track.accdb";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Data.Users> newUserList = new List<Data.Users>();
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string Query = @"SELECT id, who, payroll_number, name, ou, pool, team, rol_id  FROM users  ORDER BY id DESC AS Users";

                        OleDbCommand = Query; <-- no se que siga y me marca error


                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {

                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

quiero tener los datos en una lista y serializarla a un archivo XML para tener una lectura mas rapida de todos los datos... mi problema y pregunta es que no se que debo hacer para el query

¿como realizo la lista con una realizacion del query?

Comment: Hola.. desconozco tu modelo actual, pero que te hace pensar que bajar los datos de la DB a un xml, para despues serializarlo en una lista y pasarlo a una pantalla, va a ser mas rapido que pasar el resultado del query a la pantalla?? y lo que preguntas sobre la bajada de datos desde una BD, va a ser mejor contestado en un tutorial, bastante largo te diria. Saludos.

Comment: @gbianchi bueno, tengo entendido que hacerlo de esta manera es mas eficiente, tarda menos en cargar los datos y en realizar consultas, ya que todo lo busca en el XML y no tiene que crear conexiones a la base de datos

Comment: tenes un link de donde sacaste esa informacion?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467143/is-it-faster-to-query-a-listt-or-database] el Segundo comentario

Comment: No. Los comentarios no son conclusivos. Mas abajo dice q es exactamente lo contrario. Todo depende del escenario y los datos q estes buscando

Comment: Eso lo comprendo, aunque mi scenario creo que es necesario, reitero... Creo. Ya que lo que quiero realizer son consultas dinamicas y reemplazos de variables. me gustaria explicarte como lo quiero usar pero creo que te confundiria.

Comment: No. Es exactamente lo que hay q hacer para llegar a una solucion. Saber donde falla, para poder encontrar la solucion. Y deberias leer sobre bajada de datos desde una bd.

Comment: ¿bajada de datos en que aspecto? veras yo tengo 4 botones y dependiendo de que boton se elija se mostrara un modal (el mismo para los 4 botones) y dentro de este modal se mostraran diferentes botones (de igual manera dependiendo de que boton se haya elegido), los cuales mostraran la informacion que se tiene dependiendo de que boton se eligio desde un principio. Espero haberme explicado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te dejo como llenar una lista desde la base de datos

consulta sql:

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spListar_ConsultaConfigOtrosBcos]
AS    
BEGIN    
    SELECT cID Valor,glosaMovimiento Texto, glosaCartola Cartola, glosaBanco Banco, codBanco codigoBco 
    FROM ConfigOtrosBcos
END
```

este es mi mi clase para capturar los datos desde la BD:

```
   public class TextoValor
    {
        [ResultField("Texto")]
        public string Texto { get; set; }
        [ResultField("Valor")]
        public string Valor { get; set; }
        [ResultField("Banco")]
        public string Banco { get; set; }
        [ResultField("codigoBco")]
        public string codigoBco { get; set; }
        [ResultField("Cartola")]
        public string Cartola { get; set; }

    }
```

aqui yo me traigo la consulta del sql a una lista:

```
 public static List ConsultaConfigOtrosBcos()
        {

            Result Resultado = null;
            Base.StoreBase StoreBase = new Base.StoreBase();
            List Listado = new List();
            SpExecutor SpExecutor = SpExecutor.Create("spListar_ConsultaConfigOtrosBcos", "EuroAmerica.PortalDePagos");

            SpExecutor.GenerateExceptions = true;

            StoreBase.RegistrarEventoInicioEjecucionSp(SpExecutor);

            try
            {
                StoreBase.GestorDeReintentos.Ejecutar(() =>
                {
                    Resultado = SpExecutor.Execute();
                    StoreBase.RegistrarEventoFinEjecucionExitosa(Resultado);

                });
                if (Resultado.IsOk)
                {
                    Resultado.PopulateList(Listado, new Clases.TextoValor());
                }

                return Listado;
            }
            catch (Exception Exception)
            {
                return new List();
            }
        }
```

y aqui ya empiezo a trabajar la lista ( al final de esta parte lo trabajo con linq):

```
   public static List DataTableToListCartolaOtrosBcos(DataTable Listado, int cabID,string  cod_banco, string cod_sucursal)
        {
            List ListadoRendicion = new List();
            EuroAmericaPortalDePagos.FrontOffice.Clases.Rendicion Linea = new EuroAmericaPortalDePagos.FrontOffice.Clases.Rendicion();
            try
            {
                List ListaGlosas = ConsultaConfigOtrosBcos();
                foreach (DataRow oDR in Listado.Rows)
                {

                    Linea = new EuroAmericaPortalDePagos.FrontOffice.Clases.Rendicion();

                    long Cargo = long.Parse(oDR["Cargo ($)"].ToString() == "" ? "0" : oDR["Cargo ($)"].ToString());
                    long Abono = long.Parse(oDR["Abono ($)"].ToString() == "" ? "0" : oDR["Abono ($)"].ToString());

                    Linea.ID = long.Parse(oDR["Linea"].ToString());
                    Linea.cabID = Convert.ToInt64(cabID.ToString().Trim());
                    Linea.det_fecha = DateTime.ParseExact(oDR["Fecha"].ToString().Trim().Replace("-", "/"), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    Linea.det_tipo_movimiento = Cargo > 0 ? "C" : "A";
                    Linea.det_codigo = "0";
                    Linea.det_glosa_codigo = oDR["Descripción"].ToString();
                    Linea.det_identificador_ser = "";
                    Linea.det_num_docto = long.Parse(oDR["Serial Documento"].ToString() == "" ? "0" : oDR["Serial Documento"].ToString());
                    Linea.det_monto = Cargo > 0 ? Cargo : Abono;
                    Linea.det_codigo_sucursal = 0;
                    Linea.det_glosa_sucursal = cod_sucursal;
                    Linea.det_cuponID = 0;
                    Linea.det_banco = cod_banco;
                    Linea.det_fechaCrea = DateTime.Now;
                    var glosas = ListaGlosas.Where(e => e.Cartola == Linea.det_glosa_codigo && e.codigoBco == Linea.det_banco).ToList();
                    if (glosas.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Linea.det_glosa_codigo = glosas.FirstOrDefault().Texto;
                    }                      

                   ListadoRendicion.Add(Linea);
                }



                //List revision = new List();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return new List();
            }
            return ListadoRendicion;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que ejecutar el query:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT id, who, payroll_number, name, ou, pool, team, rol_id  FROM users  ORDER BY id DESC AS Users");
OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
        {
            Data.Users li = new Data.Users();
            li.Add(reader.GetString(1));
            li.Add(reader.GetString(2));
            li.Add(reader.GetString(3));
            li.Add(reader.GetString(4));
            ...
            newUserList.Add(li);
        }
```